# Animation code not fired when mouse is out Clip1 but mouse is inside clip 2

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

**Problem:**

When I move the mouse cursor out of Clip 1 but is above Clip 2, the MOUSE_OUT of Clip 1 does not work.

**Expectation:**

Granted that the mouse is inside Clip 2, the location of the mouse is outside of Clip 1 already, so the `function mouse_out()` of Clip 1 should fire the code inside it.

**Full code:**

I am attaching the full code so far.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

cat1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouse_over);
cat1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouse_out);
cat2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouse_over);
cat2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouse_out);
cat3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouse_over);
cat3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouse_out);
cat4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouse_over);
cat4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouse_out);
cat5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouse_over);
cat5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouse_out);

function mouse_over(e:MouseEvent)
{
    squareEaseOut(e.currentTarget,["scaleX",1.5,"scaleY",1.5]);
}

function mouse_out(e:MouseEvent)
{
    squareEaseOut(e.currentTarget,["scaleX",1,"scaleY",1]);
}

var iSquareEasingInterval:int;

//simple square easing, this can capture several properties to be animated
function squareEaseOut(mc:Object,vars:Array)
{
    var checker:int = 0;
    clearInterval(iSquareEasingInterval);

    var ini:Array = new Array();
    var accelNum:Number = 0;
    var jerkNum:Number = 0;
    var varsLength:uint = vars.length / 2;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i<varsLength; i++)
    {
        ini[i] = mc[vars[2 * i]];
    }

    function animateEasing()
    {
        checker++;
        if (compare(mc[vars[0]]+(0.25 * (vars[1] - ini[0])) / ((1 + accelNum) * (1 + accelNum)),vars[1]))
        {
            var end = new Date();
            trace("Time lapse: "+(end - startD));

            clearInterval(iSquareEasingInterval);
            accelNum = 0;
            jerkNum = 0;
            for (var j:uint = 0; j<varsLength; j++)
            {
                mc[vars[2 * j]] = vars[(2 * j) + 1];
            }
            return;
        }
        for (var k:uint = 0; k<varsLength; k++)
        {
            mc[vars[2*k]] +=  (0.26 * (vars[(2*k)+1] - ini[k])) / ((1 + accelNum) * (1 + accelNum));
        }
        accelNum += 0.150+(jerkNum*jerkNum*jerkNum);
        jerkNum +=  0.09;
    }
    function compare(a:Number,b:Number)
    {
        if (vars[1]>ini[0])
        {
            return a>b;
        }
        else if (vars[1]<ini[0])
        {
            return a<b;
        }
    }
    var startD = new Date();
    iSquareEasingInterval = setInterval(animateEasing,20);
};
```

Comment: Can you clearly explain what the problem is and what is that you are expecting? Your question seems like facts and not a problem that you are facing :)

Comment: Just tried this in a sample project and it works fine, mouse out is being called even when the items overlap. Something going on in your code?

Comment: As I said, this works in a basic Flash project that I just tried. Can you put a `trace` inside your mouse out and mouse over methods and check whether they are actually getting fired or not?

Comment: there is a trace, event is fired, but my other function is not called still.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else buddy :) Not what you have stated in your question. Update your question with the actual code that you are calling in these event handlers.

Comment: Please look at my answer below. Don't forget to vote and accept if it answers your question :). Thanks.

Comment: Well, were you able to resolve this? Don't forget to vote and accept the help that you get here! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the same method `squareEaseOut` when any mouse over or mouse out event occurs. Since you are moving your mouse immediately out of one Movie Clip and on to the other, the same method gets called twice, first for the mouse out (for the old movie clip) and then for the mouse over of the new Movie Clip. This will not result in correct behavior as the second call will override the first one as you are using `setInterval` and clearing the interval as well on every call.

While there may be multiple ways to solve this, easiest way would be to have separate methods for mouse out and mouse over, although that might lead to some code repetition. Or, you could wait for the first animation to finish and then call the other one.

You can also look at various tweening libraries available to achieve what you want, but thats not something that I would advertise here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes indeed! the public `setInterval` ID caused the problem, I created an array to handle specific `setInterval`s fired by different `MovieClips`.