# How to pass a variables to a function called by ENTER_FRAME without override

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, actionscript, haxe, openfl

**UPDATED**

I have got a big cluttery code that I want to speed up by instantiating `CubeEaseOut` Class once. I do this through the ff:

```
var myClass = new CubeEaseOut()

myClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
myClip2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
myClip3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);

function onMouseOver(e:Event){
    //made changes here
    myClass.initializer(e.currentTarget, ["scaleX",1.5,"height",200]); 
}
```

So whenever I move the mouse on any of those Clips, a function named `initializer()` inside the `CubeEaseOut` Class is called.

Inside the `CubeEaseOut` Class, I have got a code that lunches on `ENTER_FRAME` once then periodically call a function `animateThis()`.

```
package;

import goes here...

class CubeEaseOut extends Sprite {

    var here...

    public function new(){
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateThis);
    }

    public function initializer(mc:Dynamic, vars:Array<Dynamic>()){

        vars[1] //this is a Float with value 1.5
        mc[vars[0]] //is mc.scaleX

        //some other code
        //notice many variables received here are needed by other functions
        //but if I make this public, or placed outside functions, every call
        //on this function will overwrite previous values

        //other variables here

        var sp:Float = (vars[1] - mc[vars[0]])/50
    }
    private function animateThis(e:Event){
            //some other code
            //many variables from initialize() function is needed here

            iter++
            mc[vars[1]] += sp*iter

    }

}
```

The thing is, for `animateThis()` to work, it needs vars from `initializer()`. How do i pass variables from `initializer()` to `animateThis()` without the next call to `initializer()` overriding the previous vars?

**Attemps:**

1. I tried to use Global vars but this messes things up.
2. Place ENTER_FRAME inside the initializer() function but it turns out that ENTER_FRAME will be called my times - CPU intensive.
3. Created several instance of the Class - CPU intensive as well.
4. Tried using this.aVar, aVar gets overridden by the next call.

**Additional Info:**

The full code I am doing is similar to this one

[Animation code not fired when mouse is out Clip1 but mouse is inside clip 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109432/animation-code-not-fired-when-mouse-is-out-clip1-but-mouse-is-inside-clip-2/32110312#32110312)

but I am now implementing class and ENTER_FRAME.

Comment: yes, I will, I am completing the porting of my code using your suggestions. I will be back once the results are up.

Comment: @GurtejSingh users that ask a question are notified about answers that they receive. We do not have to spam the site with "look at my answer!" comments.

Comment: @null Sorry about that! I was just making sure that users do see the answer that I have posted. Will be careful moving forward. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Updated code below. As far as I understand, you want to use the same class `CubeEaseOut` to manage multiple animations. What I've tried (not tested), is to create an Array of objects of the data being passed to this class. In each object, I store the movie clip passed, and the data passed for each movie clip. Every time initializer is called it checks whether data for this movie clip already exists in the array. If it does not, it adds the movie clip and it's data to the array. If it finds the movie clip, it just assigns the object as the current animating object from the array and it does not overwrite it's data. Note that this may limit the animation to run for only one movie clip at a time.

You can choose to run a loop inside your enter frame method and perform animations for all objects inside your array.

```
import goes here...

class CubeEaseOut extends Sprite {

    private var objectsToAnimate:Array = new Array(); 
    private var currentMcData:Object;    

    public function new(){
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateThis);
    }

    public function initializer(mc:Dynamic, vars:Array<Dynamic>()){
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < objectsToAnimate.length; i++)
        {
              if (objectsToAnimate[i].movieClip != mc)
              {
                   var dataObj:Object = new Object(); 
                   dataObj.movieClip = mc; 
                   dataObj.dataVars = vars; 
                   objectsToAnimate.push(dataObj);
              }
              else if (objectsToAnimate[i].movieClip == mc)
                   this.currentMcData = objectsToAnimate[i];
        }
    }
    private function animateThis(e:Event){
            //codes here
            trace(this.currentMcData.vars);
            // or run a loop and animate all the movie clips.
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Done testing using `this.aVar` it does not work in my code. Though `this.aVar` was received by the function, it gets overridden once an immediate call to `initializer()` function was activated, i have got to pass it like it was a local var for the two functions(?)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the up vote. Secondly, let me understand your need better. Do you want this variable to be updated just once? Some more details can certainly help me update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have got about 10 variables that `animateThis()` should access from `initializer()`. Some are either updated, while others are static. I am thinking, maybe I could transfer the ENTER_FRAME event to `initializer()` then have it pass an argument. But I encounter two problems (1) there is no way I could pass arguments like it was from setInterval() and (2) I could not set an `int identifier` for each and every `addEventListener` that is lunched.

Comment: @DominicGuana The static variables can be defined inside your class itself and you can initialize them in your `CubeEaseOut` itself and they would never change. However, I am unclear about the ones which you want to update. When do you need to update them? If you want to do it in the initializer method, then since that method is called from every Mouse over, it will update. And you have only one class instance of `CubeEaseOut`

Comment: I made some changes to the above now.

Comment: @DominicGuana I updated my answer. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. Hope this works for you!

Comment: I will be update my code, and will be back for the results.

Comment: I get an Error when I try to compile it: Cannot compare Dynamic with Unknown<0>.

Comment: @DominicGuana could be a type casting issue, can you please try to debug it with break points and see? On which line do you get this error?